# Send mail using wp_mail once a vaule is updated on a table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using a plugin called wpDataTables, I created a data table. I need the selected users to receive an email once there name is added to the row "Assigned User"

How would I implement this?

I looked at a few solutions using PHP and MySQL and couldn't get any of them to work.

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `wp_wpdatatable_1` WHERE assigneduser = 'Paul';";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
        if ($query = "Paul") {
          echo "do something";
    } 
?>
```

I apologize in advance if my question is unreasonable. I just really need help with this.

the link to the website is http://status.ngage-agency.co.za/

Comment: Yes its possible

Comment: MySQL functions are deprecated and removed from PHP 7.0+. Please switch to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php) and use prepared statements to protect yourself from attacks. Or better; use [Wordpress's class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)